# Dynamic page creation and rendering from external source

Tags: react-native

I would like to build an app which content on some pages is rendered dynamically from an external source. For example, a complete form page with fields and validation rules. This page is stored on external source from the app itself and whenever the user logs in, it will get the updated page to be rendered.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways to accomplish this:

1. Server side rendering
2. Server driven rendering

**Server Side Rendering**

This is when your server stores *and* renders your components.

As defined by [Heavy.Ai](https://www.heavy.ai/technical-glossary/server-side-rendering), "Server-side rendering (SSR) is an application’s ability to convert HTML files on the server into a fully rendered HTML page for the client". This means that the page (or in React-Native's case, a component) is rendered on the server then passed to the client in a Browser/App readable format.

This allows you to store all your app files on your server, as well as render them before sending them out increasing performance for the client.

**Pros**

- Ease of indexing for browsers (increases your SEO)
- Your pages/components load faster, and (for browser purposes), your web pages load quicker for users with slower internet connection or older devices.
- You do not have to re-submit your app to the app store/google play store when updating components stored on the server

**Cons**

- This is a costly method for your server. It can be resource intensive, and it takes on the full burden of all your clients/app users, and any web-scrapers or bots that visit your page (if you use react-native browser).
- Not all native libraries may be compatible with it
- Frequent requests and full reloads for pages/components may result in slower performance than rendering on the client side

One library to accomplish this is [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/).

**Server Driven Rendering**

Server driven rendering is very similar to server side rendering, but instead of rendering on the server you render on the client. With server driven rendering, you specify *templates* (which are just your components) on your server, and these templates then are passed to the client for rendering. This is less resource intensive on your server, as rendering is pushed to clients.

One library that accomplishes this is [react-native-sdr](https://github.com/i6mi6/react-native-sdr).

Out of the two choices, both are very efficient models as you are able to reduce the size of your app by storing the scripts on a server, and in server side rendering's case you can increase the performance in some cases. From the context of the question, it sounds like **server driven rendering** would be ideal, as you want to store a template, but then render it on the Client. However, rendering dynamically from an external source would be **server side rendering**. You can combine either of these with lazy loading to ensure that the scripts are only loaded in when absolutely necessary.

Both choices **requires** internet connection (however, depending on your app size, you won't need very fast internet), as your scripts are not stored locally. So if you want your app to work offline, you will either have to download the scripts into local storage once you do receive connection or avoid these altogether.

If you want to implement either, you will need a server and a connection point between your app and the server. I have used Socket-IO and Expo (for bundling), these are user friendly for getting started.